# Finding dimension mathematically for simple equations

Tags: linear-algebra

A lot of times in my linear algebra textbook, there will be simple general equations for which it is normally easy to deduce the dimension of it. For example, take $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$

$$x_1 - x_2 + x_3 = 0$$

It is obvious is you gradually build up an equation, for example, it is likely that $x_2 = x_1$ and then $x_3$ is just 0. Or that $x_2 = \frac{1}{2}x_1$ and then $x_3 = -\frac{1}{2}x_1$. The textbook gives the dimension to be $2$, but how can I solve this rigorously without having to rely on intuition?

Comment: Write your linear system as $Ax=0$, where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix. By the rank-nullity theorem, the dimension of the solution is $$n-\operatorname{rank}(A)$$ in your case $2=3-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *rank-nullity* theorem: $V$ is the kernel of the linear map:
\begin{align*}
f\colon \mathbf R^3&\longrightarrow\mathbf R\\
\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}&\longmapsto x-y+z
\end{align*}
As this map is surjective, $\dim\ker f+1=3$.

Answer (score 1):

Each independent linear equation reduces the dimension by $1$.

So, $3$ variables and $1$ equation implies a solution set of dimension $3-1=2$.